# How to get all matching iterations for a capture group

Tags: python, regex

I made this regular expression and use it with re.findall():

```
SELECT.*{(?:\[([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)\]\.\[([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)\]\.\[([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)\][,]{0,1}){1,}}.*
```

[image: made with https://jex.im]

to match these lists of strings:

> ["dimSales","Product Title","All"],
>   ["test","Product Title","All"]

in this haystack:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[dimSales].[Product Title].[All],[test].[Product Title].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS FROM [Model] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
```

my regex only matches the last iteration of the outer capturing group

> ["test","Product Title","All"]

what do I need to change, so re.findall() returns all iterations. Not just the last iteration of the outer capturing group?

Comment: which language?

Comment: You get those matches because you first match SELECT, then match all until the end of the string `.*`. Then backtracking starts to the first occurrence of `{`. After that, you repeat a non capturing group which contains capturing groups where the capturing groups will contain the values of the last iteration. What is the tool or language that you are using?

Comment: thx the fourth bid, will try to rethink. @Allan why the downvote? regex is language agnostic.

Comment: i use python re.findall()

Comment: I didn't downvote Jabb, and regex syntax/behaviour varies a lot depending on the language. If you have PCRE/ECMAScript/BRE/ERE...

Comment: @Jabb There are a lot of different regex engines. See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines).

Comment: ok. agreed. wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @Jabb The description of the _regex_ tag even mentions it: ‘*Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.*’

Comment: oh wow.. and i wasn't aware that tags have descriptions on them. thx again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string = "SELECT NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[dimSales].[Product Title].[All],[test].[Product Title].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS FROM [Model] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS"

print re.findall(r"(?:SELECT .+\({|,)\[([\w ]+)\]\.\[([\w ]+)\]\.\[([\w ]+)\](?=[^}]*})",  string)
```

**Output:**

```
[('dimSales', 'Product Title', 'All'), ('test', 'Product Title', 'All')]
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:SELECT .+\({|,)      # non capture group, match SELECT folowed by 1 or more any character then ({ OR a comma
\[([\w ]+)\]            # group 1, 1 or more word character or space inside square brackets
\.                      # a dot
\[([\w ]+)\]            # group 2, 1 or more word character or space inside square brackets
\.                      # a dot
\[([\w ]+)\]            # group 3, 1 or more word character or space inside square brackets
(?=[^}]*})              # positive lookahead, make sure we have after a close curly bracket not preceeded by another curly bracket
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this regex:

```
(\[\"[^\"]*\",\"[^\"]*\",\"[^\"]*\"\],\s*\[\"[^\"]*\",\"[^\"]*\",\"[^\"]*\"\])
```

**demo:**

https://regex101.com/r/LaddaK/2/

**Explanations:**

- parenthesis `()` to have your capturing group, can be removed if not necessary
- `\[\"[^\"]*\",\"[^\"]*\",\"[^\"]*\"\]` to match an open bracket literally followed by a double quote, 0 to N non double quote characters (`[^\"]*`) followed by a double quote and a comma. You might have to surround all commas by `\s*` if you have want to accept space characters around them.
- you repeat another 2 times the pattern `\"[^\"]*\"` to match the first 3 words surround in brackets (you might have to adapt into `\w*` depending on your exact constraints on the strings.
- you repeat the whole block`[\"[^\"]*\",\"[^\"]*\",\"[^\"]*\"\]` after a `,\s*` to accept the whole pattern made of 2 blocks of brackets.

**Notes:**

- You might want to surround your regex with anchors (`^` and `$`)
- > ***I don't know exactly your constraints but if you want to analyse some JSON or parse any other format with infinite nested patterns repeating themselves (ex: fractals) you should not use regex.***

**EDIT after change of requirements:**

```
import re

inputStr = '[dimSales,Product Title,All], [test,Product Title,All]'
print(re.findall(r'\[(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)*\]', inputStr))
```

**output:**

```
['[dimSales,Product Title,All]', '[test,Product Title,All]']
```

Comment: thx. the values in the haystack are not quoted. And it is possible that there are n capturing groups (instead of the two in the example)

Comment: @Jabb: you want to have each string `[abc,def,ghi]` right? there is no quote surrounding the string in the brackets?

Comment: Thx. When I try to use my haystack on your answer, if does not work unfortunately.